# drawTextOnPath very slow on Android

Tags: android, performance, canvas

I draw a lot of shapes and text. I can move the painting with screentouch and all moves so smoothly. Until I paint a text on a path with drawTextOnPath.
"drawTextOnPath" slows down the drawingspeed.

Do anyone have a suggestion howto to speed up my situation ?

kind regards

Comment: Not without seeing your onDraw().  Please relevant code please.

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks a lot for your reply. I just found my mistake. I didn't realize, that my text was very big. When using small words ( what i like to draw), it draws smoothly again. So that was my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. This was my fault.

I used a very big string and I didn't see the text, because the path was too short. When using words it draws very smooth again.

Comment: You don't need to delete this, this site is designed to be a historic FAQ as well as answering your own questions.  This question and answer will be useful to people who make the same mistake in the future.  Once you can (there is a delay), accept your answer to this question by clicking the tick to the left.

Comment: Thanks, understood. 'Stackoverflow' is great. I learn more about and I love it. Have a good day.